# Where is the LSP artifact generated by Xtext

Tags: eclipse, xtext, language-server-protocol

I just tried the new Xtext 2.13 and generated a new project with Language Server Protocol support (I chose the fat jar option). However, I have no idea where the jar is. Here is what I tried searching for

```
find . -name "*shadow*"
find . -name "*lsp*"
ack "language-server"
ack "lsp"
```

But could not find it. I took a look at the parent project, but could find the Maven goal that is supposed to generate it. I also could not find information in the [release notes](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/releasenotes.html#/releasenotes/2017/10/20/version-2-13-0), which just mentions that it is supported but not where it is and how I am supposed to generate it. Also the [normal docs](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/index.html) don't have it currenly. I found an [example project](https://github.com/svenefftinge/xtext-lsp-workshop/blob/master/Reference%20Project%20Creation%20Steps.md) with Xtext and LSP, but it looks like it uses a different approach, because when I searched for the plugin used in the tutorial, it was not found in my dsl project. So (I feel stupid asking this), but where actually is this fat jar LSP artifact?

Comment: maven or gradle?

Comment: in both cases you should find the fat jar inside the .ide project

Comment: Thanks, it is suffixed by `ls`, you can write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the jar should be in the `target` (Maven) or `build` (Gradle) Folder of the `yourdsl.ide` project. it should be named `*-ls*.jar`